# This site is now Writing

Tags: discussion, site-name

In response to the recent discussion "[Should we change our name?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/should-we-change-our-name)", we've made a subtle but crucial alteration to how this site presents itself:

[image: Writing beta at writing.stackexchange.com]

As a general practice, we long ago moved away from naming sites after their audience in favor of topic, so this is in keeping with the more modern approach. Old links should seamlessly redirect from writers.stackexchange.com to writing.stackexchange.com, and the new name itself is in keeping with the description of the topic and audience already in use here for a while.

Chat may take a few days to update, so don't be surprised if you see the old name hanging on there for a while.

Comment: So what was the old name?

Comment: Writers, @Thunderforge. "Writers"